# saveAs for Excel file not working in VB.NET

Tags: excel, vb.net, save

I have a simple VB.NET routing to open a text file into Excel and then save it as a Excel file (.xlsx).  The open works file but saving fails with the NullReference Exception.

```
 FileName = "C:\Temp\BOM of " & AssyName & ".txt"
    Dim xlApp As New Excel.Application
    Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook = Nothing
    Dim xlWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet


    xlApp.Workbooks.OpenText(FileName, _
       StartRow:=1, _
       DataType:=Excel.XlTextParsingType.xlDelimited, _
       TextQualifier:=Excel.XlTextQualifier.xlTextQualifierNone, _
       Comma:=True)
    xlApp.Visible = True

    xlWorkBook.SaveAs("C:\Temp\BOM of " & AssyName & ".xlsx", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal)
    xlWorkBook.Close(True)
    xlApp.Quit()
```

Not sure what is going here. Image has failure message.

Thanks.[VB>NET Failure on saving an Excel file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BavXy.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook = Nothing` is the logical cause.

In the incomplete code you posted, you do not set `xlWorkbook` to anything. So when you go to save, `xlWorkbook` is literally `Nothing`.

Not tested, but consider:

```
xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.OpenText(FileName, _
       StartRow:=1, _
       DataType:=Excel.XlTextParsingType.xlDelimited, _
       TextQualifier:=Excel.XlTextQualifier.xlTextQualifierNone, _
       Comma:=True)
```

Comment: That was the issue. Thanks.